I need documentation to modify a harcoded project (spaghetti code) in my time of trial
I'm in my first three months of testing a new job. I applied for a tech support role, but ended up in a programmer role. Currently, I have been assigned a development that uses Spring in Java REST API with a fingerprint reader to manage the entry and exit of employees in different branches. However, my experience is focused on front end, JavaScript and web development with WordPress.
I don't want to lose my job, but I feel overwhelmed by the modifications required on this project. I would like suggestions on how to handle this situation. I want to make it clear that I am willing to learn, but I would need time to document and understand what is necessary.
Any recommendations on how to communicate this to my supervisor and how to approach learning technologies I'm not good at?
I appreciate in advance any advice you can offer me.
I have a project, I have been documenting in spring boot for a month and I have no idea how to use beans and lombok, but I have been able to understand things about the framework, I have a matroska-type project where there is a library as a root project and now several things come off. layers and levels using specific classes and entities, the next layer will be the jpa cpn connection to the database, next would be the configuration of dependencies and libraries (other than the one the project is based on), the sub project module layer that contains specific functionalities and configurations for fingerprint management and the reader interface and finally the most accessible layer contains general configurations and version control of the complete project. I don't understand why my project doesn't have drivers, help with that last one.

The question is very scattered and unclear, can you rephrase it with less technical jargon (so it can be in a form helpful to others as well) and boil it down to a specific "how to navigate the workplace" type question?  Alternatively try the software engineering stack.  See: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

This is not the best forum for your question.  However, all is not lost.  On the Software Engineering forum, there is this canonical questions that could guide you: I've inherited 200K lines of spaghetti code -- what now?

There is potentially a Workplace question here - around how to handle responsibilities that are different from what was advertised vs your skill set - however, the last paragraph kinda makes it sound like you want a technical answer, not a workplace answer. Clean up the question and focus on what you want our help with - and we can assist.

"How do I do something I never applied to doing and have no experience in, because I want to keep my job" is layering so many different problems that it becomes hard to meaningfully answer. If the job you're asked to do is not the job you applied for, are experienced in, or want to do; what's the point of having a preferred job to do in the first place?

"I applied for a tech support role, but ended up in a programmer role" Oh boy, I appreciate that you really want/need this job, but I think you have to at least consider the possibility that this is an unethical employer trying to get development work on the cheap. Pressing someone who applied for a tech support position into service as a programmer using technologies they aren't familiar with, sound like either a completely incompetent employer, or a dishonest employer trying to get something for (nearly) nothing. I'd advise starting to apply elsewhere!


how to approach learning technologies I'm not good at

One step at a time.

Take a deep breath and accept that the project is not so good, and that it is your job to do it. (You do not have to be happy, just to accept it.)
Repeat 1 until it works, and then repeat it occasionally when needed.
Concentrate on a small detail - e.g., something that you need to change.
Understand how it was implemented.
Understand how to implement the change.
Verify that the change works as expected and that it does not break other things.
Repeat from 3.

NOTE: Do NOT change the things that you do not (yet) understand. You risk to do a lot of unwanted damage.
I know about this because I had such experience myself - with spaghetti undocumented code.

Any recommendations on how to communicate this to my supervisor

Just organize a face to face meeting with your manager. During this meeting, request to have training regarding the technologies used in the project. Additionally, if possible, ask to have some support from previous developers - i.e., if any of them is still in the company.

I feel overwhelmed by the modifications required on this project

No need to feel overwhelmed. Do NOT think about all the change - you will surely NOT implement them all at once. Take a change which seems smaller and simpler, and deal with that to completion. Then move to the next. And the next. I am quite sure that nobody expects miracles from you.

I don't understand why my project doesn't have drivers, help with that last one.

WHY is mostly irrelevant. Your life will be the same whether you have the answer or not.
"doesn't have drivers" - I am 99% sure that there must be some drivers somewhere. Otherwise, the software would not be able to do the job. This might be one of the first tasks for you: understand the generic architecture of the software and find the drivers.

I need documentation

We all do :) But if you do not have it, create it. Every time when you implement a change, make sure to update the documentation too. It might help even yourself in the future, as well as other people who will work on that project.

EDIT (thanks to @MarkRotteveel for his comments)

I don't understand why my project doesn't have drivers

We do not know what that system uses, so we cannot give a definitive answer. But if the readers (for the access cards, fingerprints, retinas etc.) are complicated / advanced enough, they could have the drivers already integrated, and they might additionally have a Java REST interface to the outside world. So your server might be talking Java REST natively to those readers - if the readers "speak" Java REST too. In this case, the drivers are not visible, because they are deeply integrated in the firmware of the readers themselves.

I fail to see why a Java REST API program would have "drivers".

@MarkRotteveel: "with a fingerprint reader to manage the entry and exit of employees in different branches" The implementation is less relevant, but some kind of driver must exist for the communication with those readers. And I actually expect at least 2 kinds of drivers: one for the actual communication (which can be even easily available, as Ethernet or USB), and another one to be able to "speak" the language of the reader itself (initialization, shut down, self-diagnostics, acting on notifications from the reader...). Additionally, the Java REST API is just one of the components.

@MarkRotteveel: ... because the Java REST API alone cannot "manage the entry and exit of employees in different branches"

This sounds like a server application, which I would expect to not be directly attached to those fingerprint readers. As such, expecting drivers seems odd to me. What they are looking for sounds like it would be contained in "the reader interface". Possibly, it is actually the fingerprint readers that talk to the server application, and not the other way around.

@MarkRotteveel: Now you made me technically curious: How can that interface do the work WITHOUT implementing a driver AND WITHOUT talking to a (provided) driver? It is irrelevant on how many computers is the system implemented - some drivers must exist somewhere. And if those drivers stop working, no interface will make any difference. Or?

A driver is something for a direct connection between the computer system and a hardware peripheral. Why do you think the fingerprint reader is some simple peripheral that is directly connected to the server, and thus requires a driver? More likely, as is likely with access control systems like access cards and finger print readers, it is a full blown computer that is reached with some custom protocol or REST, or the reverse, the individual units talk with a custom protocol or REST to a central server.

@MarkRotteveel: 1. A processor is not a "full blown computer". And a simple micro-controller is all that is needed  to read a card. So it is quite possible that the reader could have Ethernet, but possibly not REST interfaces. For reading fingerprints, the HW is more complicated, but again - a microntroller or DSP could do the job, without the need of Java. So one of us is right and the other wrong, depending of the technology of the readers. I prefer to be the right one, but I do not mind being wrong  - in this case. Unfortunately, even OP cannot help us - not yet. I will update the answer.
